# python fails to run due to a call of jupiter notebook in another file (not related)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I simply want to run a .py file in a folder where a .ipynb file exists. It results (using visual studio code) in this error

```
(venv) PS Z:\python>  & 'z:\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe'     'c:\Users\matth\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '55920' '--' 'Z:\python\OrganiseAndFindDubplicatePicture.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\matth\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_file_utils.py", line 876, in get_abs_path_real_path_and_base_from_file
    return NORM_PATHS_AND_BASE_CONTAINER[filename]
KeyError: 'vscode-notebook-cell:/z%3A/python/OrganisePictures.ipynb#W3sZmlsZQ%3D%3D'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using (**Run Without Debugging`Ctrl+F5`**) to execute the script, which is cited to the configuration in ***launch.json*** this time.

[image]

You can use `Run Python File` to execute the script directly.

[image]

*Modify your script content to `print("hello")`. If you can run a simple statement successfully, it may be that your code is a problem instead of execution.*